# i have problem with css in django ,css affect don't show in browser

Tags: html, css, django

I'm new in Django.

I have no errors in code but `CSS` affect don't show in browser this my codes and my project folders

this is base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<title>Investissement | Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/
iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>.....
```

this is home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div id="home-content">
<h1>Investissement @2019</h1>
<h3>Your voice Matter!</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is styles.css

```
h1 {
color :red;
}

body{

background-image: url('../img/p.jpg');
}

#home-content {
text-align:left;
padding-top:20%;
}
```

in settings file i do this :

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL =' /static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/p-amc-dgps-er/Bureau/investissement/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
```

note: the static folder and templates are in same repertory with manage.py

the result no css affect are show and no code error

Comment: what does your console say?

Comment: You have a typo: `herf="`

Comment: Did you try `collectstatic` before running the server?

Comment: ivan starostin i do not understand what you mean by herf=" there is problem in this ? Sukumar Rdjf i do collectstatic before running server and always same thing no css effects

Comment: Yes, herf != href.

Comment: ivan starostin i correct it  and always same problem no css affects shows

Comment: What url is generated for this css file in rendered page? What happens if you try to open this url manually?

Comment: Ivan what you mean by rendred file it is home.html file ? And you mean when i runserver and tape 127.0.0.1:8000/home ? If you mean i tell you that page is show but without css affects and without errors

Comment: Right click, "View page source", what is the css file url here `<link rel="stylesheet"` ?

Comment: hello Ivan Starostin ..this is the url in view page source <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" /static/css/styles.css"> i think is correct

Comment: What happens if you try to open this url manually?

Comment: when i open it manually he show me page not found 404  Using the URLconf defined in Invest_App.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:admin/
home/
^compte/
immob/$ [name='immob']
^\ \/static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, static/css/styles.css, didn't match any of these.

Comment: DEBUG=False or True? And show your urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times browsers will cache files like css to improve loading speed. You can disable that in browser in order to get the latest version of file (especialy important for development). If you are in Chrome you can do that by opening developer tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I or F12) and on the `Network tab` there is a `Disable cache` button.

Comment: hi petar Jalusic  i try this and no changes always no effect